# Format in markdown server or client side? nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, client, markdown

I want to use markdown in a website, I'm wondering about convert markdown to HTML client side or server side. I'll use https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js that has both client/server libraries. (node.js)

I never used markdown before and I'm wondering about the efficience of the two ways, the security too, because I don't want to have html tags from users (injections)

Do you have any advice or explanation about why do it client side or server side? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I think that if I want to use markdown on the client, such as error handling, I must convert markdown to html in the client... So there should be no point to use it from server too. Am I right?

Comment: server side is the first choice unless you have a reason to render on client side.

Comment: Yes, it's what I thought first, but, if for example the user press a button and get a message, it this message is from a user variable treatment then I can't use markdown (Field password is required), you see?

Comment: Server side for the initial request - then client side for ajax updated content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for efficiency, you should use the same module to render at both server-side and client-side.

Server side rendering is needed for initial request, and if your data is updated somehow by user, it needs to be re-rendered at the client-side.

Reasons:

- client-side rendering is too slow for initial request because user needs to fetch all libraries first
- server-side rendering is too slow for using after the page is loaded because it needs additional requests